# What word category do twink, adonis, muse etc. belong to?

Tags: semantics, corpora, lexical-semantics, meaning

Terms such as *candy*, *cutie*, *honey*, *princess*, *diamond*, *queen*(?), *stud* and *bunny* are [terms of endearment](https://englishlive.ef.com/blog/language-lab/sweetheart-love-darling-typical-british-terms-endearment/) (these terms are often used in a relationship to show affection and may also be used, with limitations, more casually: "what can I get you, hun?”).

I was wondering to what category or categories the following terms belong: 
*cougar*, *cub*, *virgin*, *twink*, *adonis*, *giant*, *stallion*, *muse*. Is there an umbrella term for such words?

Comment: This is not off-topic but needs clarity. What sort of category are you looking for? "Terms of endearment" is not really a category of words as much as how words are sometimes used.

Comment: They can all be used as vocatives, i.e, second-person nouns.